# Loading an image from a subdirectory in a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubygame

I used bundler to create a new gem, and I'm playing with rubygame. So far, it's going OK, except I can't get images on the Surface because I can't figure out what the path is to my images directory. I know it's sad, but I'm sorta used to Rails loading my images for me.

The full path to the image is: `/usr/local/src/jewel_thief/lib/jewel_thief/images/player.png`.

and I'm trying to use it in:

`/usr/local/src/jewel_thief/lib/jewel_thief/player.rb` ([view source](https://gist.github.com/3945589#file_player.rb))

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@image = Surface.load 'jewel_thief/images/player.png'
```

To

```
@image = Surface.load '/jewel_thief/images/player.png'
```

I think following also work

```
@image = Surface.load '/jewel_thief/lib/jewel_thief/images/player.png'
```

Comment: A forward slash! Why didn't I think of that? LOL

Comment: Is it works for you? If yes accept the answer so that it's easy for the other user to solve there problem.

Answer (score 0):

The path ended up being this:

```
@image = Surface.load 'lib/jewel_thief/images/player.png'
```

Finally, after being stumped for hours. Thanks for the help though! Really.